# Insert multiple values as array into one column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have a checkbox with multiple values to be selected. So far I got it working and the data is inserting into the database but it's in this format,

[image: The image shows the values being 1,2,3]

My issue is that I want the data to be in this format **["value1","value2","value3"]**. I'm using Laravel and this is the code in my controller:

```
public function store(NewsRequest $request) //ive removed most of the unnecessary code like the image upload and all to make this clean.
{
    $news = new News($request->except('files', 'image'));
    $serialize = implode(",", $news->majors); //this is my focus to change the format to ["value1","value2","value3"]

    //ready data for insertion
    $data = array(
        "name" => $news->name,
        "article_type_id" => $request->category,
        "majors" => $serialize,
        "content" => $news->content
    );

    DB::table('articles')->insert($data); //insert into database
}
```

Currently I'm only able to insert the data with a comma separating them but I want the data to be inserted like the following:

[image]

I tried looking around the internet but I couldn't find anything that could help besides JSON.stringify. I'm hoping to get the format in my controller itself. I'm hoping to get some insight for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just add quotation marks as part of implode string - `implode('","', $news->majors);` and concatenate same quotation marks at beginning and end of the produced string.

Comment: try this: `'['.implode('","', $news->majors).']'`

Comment: Have you tried `json_encode($news->majors)`?

Comment: Thank you both! '['.implode('","', $news->majors).']' did the trick! :)

Comment: Do not do this. Data in a database needs to be normalised otherwise you will have problems further down the road. Use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Nigel, yes but json encode does not have all the quotations. @apokryfos, I have no choice, I'm working on revamping outdated admin panel for an old website and the data on their database is too much to restructure the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

adding quotation marks at the beginning , within implode() and at the end will do the magic.

```
$serialize = '["'.implode('","', $news->majors).'"]';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using json attribute for column in migration file and then in related model you can cast that column as array